# Send e-mail using Assigned To

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint Designer 2007.  I have a workflow that sends out an e-mail to admins when certain conditions are met.  What I am struggling with is getting the Assigned To data in the TO part of the e-mail.  I can do a lookup to get the Assigned To value in the body of the e-mail, but not in the actual To field (as Assigned To just isn't one of the options to select in this field, and any attempt to add this just doesn't translate at all into any sort of readable e-mail address).

So, my question is, how do I, using a workflow generated e-mail, send e-mail notifications utilizing the Assigned To field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to have an action (preceding the "send email" action in the workflow) in which you set a variable equal to the value of the "Assigned To" field, retrieving the field value as an email address. Then use that variable as the recipient in your send email action.